# What is the difference in meaning between "European history" and "the history of Europe"?

Tags: adjectives, adjectivals

Looking for a comprehensive explanation as regards to the difference in meaning

Comment: Why do you think there's a difference?

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no difference.

As with, for example: "The novels of Dickens", and "Dickensian Novels".